# PHP and MYSQL dates error

Tags: php, mysql

This is the strptime to human time function...

**PHP:**

```
function humanTiming($tm,$rcs = 0)
{
       $cur_tm = time(); $dif = $cur_tm-$tm;
       $pds = array('second','minute','hour','day','week','month','year','decade');
       $lngh = array(1,60,3600,86400,604800,2630880,31570560,315705600);
       for($v = sizeof($lngh)-1; ($v >= 0)&&(($no = $dif/$lngh[$v])<=1); $v--); if($v < 0) $v = 0; $_tm = $cur_tm-($dif%$lngh[$v]);

       $no = floor($no); if($no <> 1) $pds[$v] .='s'; $x=sprintf("%d %s ",$no,$pds[$v]);
       if(($rcs == 1)&&($v >= 1)&&(($cur_tm-$_tm) > 0)) $x .= time_ago($_tm);
       return $x;
}
```

The function works just fine, but when I pass a MySQL timestamp through it reaches an error and displays and unrealistic date like 40 years ago...

If I send a MySQL timestamp to the function **ex:**

```
2015-02-25 12:23:34
```

This is the the error I reach it returns this

```
4 decades
```

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use strtotime() and date() ?

Comment: A MySQL time is held as a string, while `time()` returns an integer value of seconds since 1st Jan 1970. You can't simply take one from another. Convert your MySQL time to an integer timestamp first.

Comment: When you say '40 years ago', you mean sometime at or around 1st Jan 1970?

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime('2015-02-25 12:23:34')` that should do the trick.

strtotime converts a string to a unix timestamp, which is required in your function.

If you pass a string to that function like `2015-02-25 12:23:34`, it converts it to 0 as the unix timestamp. 0 seconds since Jan 01 1970, so that over 4 decades ago. 
Some documentation on this here http://unixtimestamp.com

Comment: Maybe it will, but you should explain why.

Comment: strtotime converts a string to a unix timestamp, which is required in your function. If you pass a string to that function like 2015-02-25 12:23:34, it converts it to 0 as the unix timestamp.
0 second since Jan 01 1970, so that over 4 decades ago. http://www.unixtimestamp.com/ as documentation